# How To Redirect URL To Another URL

Tags: .htaccess

Let say i've website of url `http://-*-my-site-url-*-.com` and i've installed SSL Certificate so i want using `.htaccess` to automatically redirect any visitor

hit `http://-*-my-site-url-*-.com` **To** `https://-*-my-site-url-*-.com` (Notice https://)

what is the `.htaccess` code should i add and will it change the sub-pages too **OR** only main page .

Thanks

Comment: there is better place for such questions like serverfault :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the following lines to your htaccess file :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}    off
RewriteRule (.*)     https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

The first line tells Apache we are going to use mod_rewrite. The second line checks to see if it is using ssl. If that second line matches then the third uses variables (better than using `-*-my-site-url-*-.com`) to redirect the user to the SSL version of your URL.

Answer (score 2):

Simple and Straight forward code will work for all the url.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```